# jQuery: How to toggle the select attribute in a select list's options on the click of a radio button without duplicating the select list?

Tags: jquery

I have a question about select lists and the selected attribute. I've done some research and haven't found a solution that works yet, so I ask you folks for your input and thank you in advance.

Here's what's going on. When I click on one of two radio buttons, I would like that selection to allow me to change the position of the "selected" attribute in the option tags. I need it to go from:

```
<option value="_blank">Blank</option>
```

and then change to this after the radio button for external is selected.

```
<option value="_self" selected>Self</option>
```

Hopefully that makes sense, here's what it looks like.

HTML: (note that there's other stuff going on that tells it to toggle, which I use to select the target link source data-target when it's checked)

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="link_source" class="generic-form__label">Link Source</label>
   <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="link_source" value="internal" data-target="internal" checked> Internal</label>
   <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="link_source" value="external" data-target="external"> External</label>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <label for="link-target" class="label">Link Target</label>
  <select name="link_target" id="link-target" class="input">
    <option value="_blank">Blank</option>
    <option value="_parent">Parent</option>
    <option value="_self">Self</option>
    <option value="_top">Top</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

jQuery: 
basically I've tried this, and it works on the page load, but when I try to toggle back and forth between internal and external, it doesn't switch, it stays on external and selects Blank. There are other things going on like setting that variable target, which works. It logs the correct target id.

```
if (target === 'external') {
    $('select option[value="_blank"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
     console.log('it found ' + target)
     if (target !== 'interal') {
        $('select option[value="_blank"]').removeAttr('selected', 'selected');
     }
  }
  else if (target === 'internal'){
    $('select option[value="_self"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    if (target !== 'external') {
        $('select option[value="_blank"]').removeAttr('selected', 'selected');
     }
    console.log('it found ' + target)
  }
```

**EDITED FOR CLARITY**

Comment: Mr. McCoy makes a valid point, you have 2 radio buttons yet there are 4 options....we need a better explanation as to how an input (2 radios) will double it's output to control 4 options.

Comment: I didn't really think about that being a problem! Thanks for pointing it out. I'm not even sure if it's meant to have four options in the first place. But either way, I think snagging the data attribute would be a good method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two radio buttons but 4 options in the select. Basically you need to store the value of the option inside the radio button's data attribute. The code below should get you started:

HTML

```
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="link_source" value="internal" data-target="_self" checked> Internal</label>
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="link_source" value="external" data-target="_blank"> External</label>
```

JQuery

```
$('input[type=radio][name=link_source]').on('change', function() {
  var selectValue = $(this).data('target');
  $('#link-target').val(selectValue).change();
});
```

Try that out and let me know if you need additional instruction.

Comment: All set! For others out there: after $('#link-target').val(selectValue).change(); I was able to add an if statement that checked for which value was being targeted, then assigned the selected attribute to the option I wanted by doing $('select').val('_self')

Answer (score 1):

Just use the .val() method of the select and assign it a value, it will automatically select/unselect the options for you, as per the documentation on the jquery site.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. That's not quite what I'm targeting. I want the option in the dropdown to have the attribute selected, I don't want to change the value.

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean now. Hmmm.

Comment: I enjoyed watching that light turn on. :D  Have a great evening.  The example below that McCoy gave is what you are wanting.  Either store the related select option in the data tag of the radio or use a switch statement in your click handler.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try it out in a bit!